# Get PHP proc_open() to read a PhantomJS stream for as long as png is created

Tags: php, phantomjs, proc-open

I had a PHP script that relied on `shell_exec()` and (as a result) worked 99% of the time.
The script executed a PhantomJS script that produced an image file.
Then using more PHP that image file was processed in a certain way.
Problem was that on occasion `shell_exec()` would hang and cause usability issues.
Reading this
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11463
I learnt that `shell_exec()` is the problem and switching to `proc_open` would solve the hanging.

The problem is that while `shell_exec()` waits for the executed command to finish `proc_open` doesn't, and so the PHP commands that follow it and work on the generated image fail as the image is still being produced.
I'm working on Windows so `pcntl_waitpid` is not an option.

What I'm trying to do is continuously have PhantomJS output something (anything) so that `proc_open` would read via it's stdin pipe and that way I can time the image processing PHP functions to start working as soon as the target image file is ready.

here is my phantomJS script:

```
interval = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("x");
}, 250);
var page = require('webpage').create();
var args = require('system').args;
page.open('http://www.cnn.com', function () {
  page.render('test.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

And my PHP code:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
    2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr 
);

$process = proc_open ("c:\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe /test.js", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
if (is_resource($process))
{
while( ! feof($pipes[1]))
  {
     $return_message = fgets($pipes[1], 1024);
     if (strlen($return_message) == 0) break;
     echo $return_message.'<br />';
     ob_flush();
     flush();
  }
}
```

The test.png is generated, but I am not getting a single `$return_message`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As [Bill Shander suggested](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11463#issuecomment-22643468) right in your linked github issue, you can use:

```
Proc_Close(Proc_Open("phantomjs test.js &", Array (), $foo));
```

to run your phantomjs script (which is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46008/1816580)). It seems that you only need the image, so the pipes are not necessary in this case.

Complete script for reference is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0d209c0a35672a35690c) and works on windows as is.